# Preserving features in xlsx file with python

Tags: python, excel, format, openpyxl

I'm working in doing some work with python and excel. In this case I have to modify an `.xlsx` document and then save the document. But the issue is, the original document have especial format and style. I need to preserve the format after the work. This is some code I'm using.

```
import openpyxl as xl
*#open the file* 
wb = xl.load_workbook("CR_Accounts_Dashboard_V4_20170127.xlsx") 

*#...
#...
# Do some stuff
#...
#...*

*#save the file*
wb.save("CR_Accounts_Dashboard_V4_20170127.xls")
```

So after saving the file the original format and style are been removed.

This is one sheet in the original file
[image: This is one sheet in the original file]
After working in the file and saving it
[image: After working in the file and saving it]
Here we have another example

This is another sheet in the original file
[image: Example2]
After working in the file and saving it
[image: After working in the example 2]

Does anyone have any idea about preserving the format and style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not reproduce your problem
**Give us your used Version of openpyxl**

Try the following, without doing annything else, and verify if the problem persists:

```
wb = xl.load_workbook("CR_Accounts_Dashboard_V4_20170127.xlsx")
wb.save("CR_Accounts_Dashboard_V4_20170127.xls")
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - openpyxl:2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 4.3.3.2***

Comment: Hi sorry for the long time, i was out of the country. I´m using python 3.6.0, openpyxl 2.4.2 and excel 2013. Still having the same issue

Comment: @Carlos Ok, you are using the newest version. Please edit your question to explain your *especial format and style* more detailed?

Answer (score 0):

It says quite clearly in the [documentation that charts in existing files are not preserved](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/charts/introduction.html)

For the rest it looks like you may be using tables or even pivot tables. Support for worksheet tables with be in version 2.4.4 (you'll need to use a checkout until it's released) but pivot tables are not supported: it's a lot of work and so far no one has been prepared to sponsor the development.